# iOS Push Notifications - Show in Top Bar When Phone isn't locked

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

How can I make my push notification alert for my app show in a top rectangle on the phone when it's not locked. Right now I only see it on the locked screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to display push notifications when you app is running and in the foreground? That is, you want notifications that are received while your app is running to look just like notifications that are received when your app is not running? Unfortunately, iOS has no support for this. When your app is in the foreground, it is notified via [UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:] when a notification is received, but nothing is displayed.  You'll have to write your own UI code to display a banner at the top of the screen when this method is called.

Comment: No, I meant that when my app is running in the background, but the phone is not locked - I get the notification (i.e I hear the alert) but I don't see anything visually - I want a popup bar to load on the top of the screen or something. When the phone is locked - there's a bar showing the notification.